# Why am I get a type error in the loss function of a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tensorflow 2.8.4

I've built the following example where I'm keeping the input and outputs the same since I don't think I need to define anything extra in the outputs (I may be wrong in thinking this):

```
features = {
    'prop1': ['BT', 'BT', 'BT'],
    'prop2': [1000,1000,1000],
    'prop3': [1, 1, 0],
}

labels = [1, 1, 0]

inputs = {
    'prop1': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), dtype='string'),
    'prop2': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), dtype='int64'),
    'prop3': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), dtype='int64'),
}

example_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, inputs)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))

example_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
)

example_model.fit(dataset, epochs=1)
```

This example is similar to the one provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_feature_columns#with_keras_preprocessing_layers) but also a simplified version of a larger model I'm currently troubleshooting. I had to go back to basics and build something simple like this in the hopes of making progress.

Unfortunately, I still get the following error:

```
File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/home/benfranklin/.pyenv/versions/train28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1923, in binary_crossentropy
        label_smoothing = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_smoothing, dtype=y_pred.dtype)

    TypeError: Expected string, but got 0.0 of type 'float'.
```

Comment: `BinaryCrossentropy` expects floats. It will not work with int or string

Comment: Seems like that you send the output of your model, which is a dictionary (dtypes of string and int64), along with the target labels, which is a list of three items here (int32), to the loss function, which leads to the error. In other words, your `y_pred` and `y_true` are not compatible.

Comment: @AndrzejO I see your point about `BinaryCrossEntropy` expecting floats but that still doesn't explain to me the complaint about strings here. The loss function (unless I've misunderstood) is based on the y-values, which I'm quite sure are the labels in this case.

Comment: @learner I thought the lost function was supposed to be a function of the y-values (or labels) not a function of the inputs.

Comment: @BenFranklin That is correct, but according to your model definition, `tf.keras.Model(inputs, inputs)`, the output of your model is still the same dictionary as the input. So, the loss function receives `y_true` (labels) together with `y_pred` that is the same as the input here (I don't know the logic behind the way the model is defined though).

Comment: @learner in that case I'm confused as to what the outputs should be since in my mind the outputs are the y-values (each one provided by a slice from the x-values) provided by the labels. The actual outputs parameter is for some kind of preprocessing which in my case I don't feel is required. Are the outputs actually supposed to be the labels?

Comment: You defined one string input, and then made a model that outputs its input, so it is outputting a string, which makes no mathematical sense. Put some thought into that.

Comment: @BenFranklin If BinaryCrossentropy receives not floats, for example `string` or `int`: then y_pred.dtype will be a string or int. But `label_smoothing` is a float! That's why then `tf.convert_to_tensor` will complain with the error message you see

Comment: @BenFranklin Not all functions perform type checking of the arguments. If you give them arguments with the wrong type, you can get misleading error messages or some other undefined behaviour

Comment: You need to use `StringLookup()` to convert string column('prop1') into integer indices as mentioned into the same linked [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_feature_columns#with_keras_preprocessing_layers). Also please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212951/this-error-was-occured-typeerror-expected-int64-got-1e-07-of-type-float-in) for your reference.