# Can't use Keras' CosineSimilarity in Tensorflow2.7

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm running TF 2.7 (I need it in that version). I'm trying to use the `Keras.losses.CosineSimilarity` loss function to train a Keras model (Stellargraph GCN model). But everytime a strange error stops the training process. I can confirm that it is related to using CosineSimilarity.

The error:=

TypeError: Expected int64 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Maximum', got 1e-12 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected int64, but got 1e-12 of type 'float'.

Here is the code :=

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers, losses, metrics, Model
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Model(inputs=x_inp, outputs=predictions)
similarity = losses.CosineSimilarity()
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
    loss = similarity,
    metrics= [Precision],
)

es_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_F1", patience=50, restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(
    train_gen,
    epochs=500,
    validation_data=val_gen,
    verbose=2,
    shuffle=False,  
    callbacks=[es_callback],
)
```

I can confirm that all of my training & validation data are of the integer type.

Comment: so you are saying that if you just change `similarity = losses.CosineSimilarity()` with `similarity = losses.MeanSquaredError()` it works fine?

Comment: I'm solving a classification problem. However, just changing the loss function from cosine similarity to binary cross entropy works ok. But I need to operate with the cosine similarity for this problem.

Comment: you have answered my question. please, change ONLY THAT LINE as see if it works... so we know that the problem is specifically that single line

Comment: Done so before, it is with that specific line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a confusing error message and you should actually cast your data to `float32`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695086/tensorflow-basic-rnn-seq2seq-typeerror-expected-int32-got-0-1-of-type-float) for an example of similar error.

In your case I think `CosineSimilarity` actually calculates the addition of the product of the norms (that is `int32` here because your data are `int32`) and an `epsilon` (`float32` seems to be equal to 1e-12) for denominator. It expects that `epsilon` to be a `int32` to proceed the addition and raises this error. However in you case what you need is to change the data type to `float32` instead.